# Scala spark dataframe hive conversion

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark

Hi in hive query I am using below syntax for displaying decimal values ex.

```scala
Cast( column as decimal(10,6)).
```

Same syntax how to convert in data frame.

```scala
$"column".cast("decimal(10,6)")
```

Will that work

Comment: Why don't you just try it?

Comment: In travel. So not able to try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will. It totally legit to cast it like that:

```
df.withColumn("new_column_name", $"old_column_name".cast("decimal(10,6)"))
```

Comment: Let me try and confirm with you